# Character count with multiple limits

Tags: javascript, for-loop, character, counter

I'm new to javascript and I'm trying to write a script that determines the character count of a boxarea and then compares the count length to an array of character limits. If the boxarea count is more than a given limit, the array element has a different class toggled.

If I'm being confusing, maybe this (very bad :*) script will help:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    limit1.count = 10;
    limit2.count = 15;
    limit3.count = 20;


    function getCount (textarea) {
        var i=0;
        for (i=0;i<=5;i++)
        {
        if(textarea.value.length > limit[i].count) {
            $(limit[i].toggleClass("unavailable");
        }
        }
        }
});
```

Comment: 1. Where and what are limit1,limit2,limit3 (where are they assigned for instance?); 2. How do you call `getCount`; 3. Where is the 5 coming from in your for loop?; 4. why do you have `limit1` then try to reference it like an array (is it supposed to be one?); 5. Do you anticipate the class to be toggled more than once if the value is really long (from what I see it will, and an even number of toggles will look like it was never toggled).

Comment: Limit 1,2,3 etc. are assigned by me. I'm assuming I would call getCount with a separate script for example $(textarea).getCount();. The limit is also the name of the div that I wish to toggle a separate class on. Should I provide the full example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be your style:

```
<style type="text/css">
.box {width: 100px; height: 100px; display: block; margin: 10px; float: left;
    background-color: green;}
.unavailable {background-color: red;}
</style>
```

The HTML:

```
<div><textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea></div>

<div id="box1" class="box">Box 1</div>
<div id="box2" class="box">Box 2</div>
<div id="box3" class="box">Box 3</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>  
    function validate()
    {
        var validation = { 
            '#box1': 10, 
            '#box2': 15,
            '#box3': 20
        }; 

        $.each(validation, function(elem, max) { 
            $(elem).removeClass("unavailable");
            if($('#textarea').val().length > max)
                $(elem).addClass("unavailable");
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $('#textarea').keydown(validate);
        validate();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Eric, thanks! Definitely on the right track. If my textarea box is called "quote", would I invoke your function with a separate script like $(quote).validate(); ? Secondly, the validation counts (e.g. id1, id2), are also the names of the div's I wish to change the class for.

Comment: An id must be unique. '#id1' is an ID so it should be only used by one element (whether your div OR your textarea). I've changed my answer a bit to include an usage example.

Comment: I just tried it but it doesn't work. Not sure where to look for the problem :(

Comment: Yes that was it! Amazing! Last question, is it possible to run the function dynamically i.e. without the "validate" button? Validation would occur automatically as the user is entering text.